# VBA Loop - copy and paste cells into next column until cell x equals cell y

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I need some help looping. I have not used VBA for sometime and starting to learn again. I remember this community helped me a lot in the past so any help is appreciated.

**The Challenge**

I want to copy cell H12 into the next empty column starting with i12 then J12 and so forth. So I want to continue the loop until the the number of pasted arrays equal the number in cell D12. So if Cell D12 = 20 I want to continue this loop copying H12 until I get to AB12.

Then once this is complete I want to move to the next row H13 and do the same thing. In this case D13 = 15 so we do the same as above copying H13 until we get to R13.

Any help is really appreciated. I have tried some loops for other things which have not worked out.

Comment: I tried a for loop but I could not get it to copy for a the number in D12. I also found it difficult to copy into the next empty cell. So I am starting from a very low VBA skill level.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption, that your selected cell is H12 and the cells right of it are empty and D12 is filled with a positive numeric value, the following code should work:

```
Sub CopyToRange()

Dim ThisCol As Integer, ThisRow As Long, CurS As Worksheet, CurRg As Range, InfCol As Integer

Set CurS = ActiveSheet
ThisRow = ActiveCell.Row
ThisCol = ActiveCell.Column
InfCol = 4 'column 'D'
Set CurRg = Range(CurS.Cells(ThisRow, ThisCol + 1), CurS.Cells(ThisRow, ThisCol + CurS.Cells(ThisRow, InfCol).Value))
ActiveCell.Copy
CurRg.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

End Sub
```

If you select the next row with the same preconditions it will work as well

Answer (score 0):

### Duplicate Cell Values

**Usage (OP)**

- Copy all of the code into a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**How to Test (Anyone)**

- Add a new workbook (or just open `Excel`). In `VBE` add a new standard module and copy the code into it. In `Excel`, in worksheet `Sheet1`, in column `D` starting from cell `D12`, add some positive integers (whole numbers), and in the respective cells in column `H` add the values to be duplicated. Run the `DuplicateCellValues` procedure.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DuplicateCellValues()
    ' Needs the 'RefColumn' function.
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Duplicate Cell Values"
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "D12" ' Column 'D': number of duplicates.
    Const dfCol As String = "H" ' Column 'H': value to duplicate.
    
    ' Create a reference to the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    ' Create a reference to the Source First Cell ('sfCell').
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = ws.Range(sFirst)
    ' Create a reference to the Source Column Range ('scrg').
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = RefColumn(sfCell)
    ' Check if no data in the Source Column Range was found.
    If scrg Is Nothing Then
    ' Inform and exit.
        MsgBox "There is no data in the one-column range '" _
            & sfCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1).Address(0, 0) _
            & "'.", vbCritical, ProcTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCell As Range ' Current Source Cell
    Dim drrg As Range ' Destination Row Range
    Dim dfCell As Range ' Destination First Cell
    
    ' Loop through the cells ('sCell') of Source Column Range.
    For Each sCell In scrg.Cells
        ' Create a reference to the current Destination First Cell.
        Set dfCell = sCell.EntireRow.Columns(dfCol)
        ' Attempt to create a reference to the Destination Row Range.
        ' It may fail if there is no whole number in the current Source Cell,
        ' or if the number is too small, or if it is too big,... etc.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set drrg = dfCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, sCell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' If the reference was created...
        If Not drrg Is Nothing Then ' *** Destination Row Range referenced.
            ' Write the value from the current First Destination Cell
            ' to the cells of the Destination Row Range.
            drrg.Value = dfCell.Value
            ' Dereference the Destination Row Range for the 'On Error Resume Next'
            ' to work 'correctly'.
            Set drrg = Nothing
        'Else ' *** Destination Row Range NOT referenced.
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Cells duplicated.", vbInformation, ProcTitle
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub duplicate()
        Dim arr, LastRow As Long
        With Sheet8
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            arr = .Range(.Cells(12, 4), .Cells(LastRow, 100)).Value2
        End With
        
        Dim j As Long, i As Long, ii As Long: ii = 1
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            For i = 6 To 5 + (arr(j, 1) * ii)
                arr(j, i) = arr(j, 5)
            Next i
        Next j
        
        With Sheet8
            .Range(.Cells(12, 4), .Cells(LastRow, 100)) = arr 'dump updated array to invoice sheet
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: This gets stuck with a bug at    arr(j, i) = arr(j, 5)

Comment: What are the values of j and I when it gets stuck?